# TYPO3 MAGEconnect - images issue

Tags: magento, soap, typo3

I have problem with images and MAGEconnect extension. All data from magento are transferred (using SOAP) to TYPO3 expect images.

Code on page looks like this:

```
<a href="http://store.com/computer.html" target="_self">
     <img src="" width="" height="" alt="" />
</a>
```

On FTP server in catalog `uploads/tx_mageconnect` there are stored all photos but all have 0kB size. I used standard config of extension.

Any suggestion?

Thanks for any help,

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - missing `index.php/` in the Magento URL config